# Automapper with Tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm Trying to map object in to tuple which returns three objects i have added configuration as below

```
 CreateMap<JobDto, (Job Job, JobDetail JobDetail, Location Location)>()
    .ForMember(des => des.Job,
        exp => exp.MapFrom(src => new Job
        {
            UserId = src.UserId,
            CategoryId = src.CategoryId,
            Title = src.Title,
            Description = src.Description
        }))
    .ForMember(des => des.JobDetail, exp => exp.MapFrom(src => new JobDetail
    {
        Duration = src.Duration,
        DurationType = src.DurationType,
        PayAmount = src.Amount,
        PayType = src.PayType
    }))
    .ForMember(des => des.Location, exp => exp.MapFrom(src => new Location
    {
        Latitude = src.Latitude,
        Longitude = src.Longitude,
        Address = src.Address
    })).ReverseMap();
```

but when I try to map object:

```
var map = _mapper.Map<(Job Job, JobDetail JobDetail, Location Location)>(obj);
```

it throws exception:

> Unmapped properties: Item1 Item2 Item3
>
> at
>   AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1
>   typeMaps)    at lambda_method(Closure , JobDto , ValueTuple`3 ,
>   ResolutionContext )    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ,
>   ResolutionContext )    at
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)

Could anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE

and then i tried with this

```
(Job Job, JobDetail JobDetail, Location location) map = (null, null,null);
var newMap = _mapper.Map(obj, map);
```

worked perfectly.. why?

Comment: Can you open a GitHub issue? Tuples in C# are a ton of syntactic sugar, so it may be something we just missed in that sugar. Also, those MapFrom's look really weird...any time I see properties match up exactly in explicit config, it's a red flag.

Comment: sure i will open an issue